# What hardware is important for streaming PC games?

Tags: streaming, hardware-rec

I'm planning on building a streaming computer. I'm wondering what to keep in mind when putting this computer together. What hardware is most important for streaming of PC games? I will use XSplit as software and stream on Twitch.

Comment: You probably need a way to connect to the internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast hard drive/SSD, CPU with enough cores to have some extra for capturing software, high resolution monitor for high-res captures, powerful GPU setup to allow for 60fps captures.

Comment: Why do I need the SSD? Isn't everything stored on RAM rather than on the Harddisk?

Comment: @robin that depends on a game. Some read from HDD(or SSD), some from the RAM. Even though most is stored on a RAM, I know games who read certain stuff(like sound) from HDD(which is kinda retarded... saving ~200MB of RAM and lowering the speed). Also the spec depends on a game. Be more specific, list a game(or the heavist) you want to stream.

Comment: @Robin No, not everything is stored there. Games usually resort to texture streaming meaning that they will access the HDD during gameplay. At the same time you're capturing to it adding more stress to it and increasing the chances for framedrops. You don't need SSDs, but those are quick and probably best for capturing game footage. Most people on Youtube who capture to 4K use SSDs since no hard drive could deal with the influx of data. Alternatively, use two hard drives. One to install the game and OS to and one to capture to.

Comment: Alright. I will be streaming League of Legends, SC2, CS:GO, Dota2 etc. Why is a good monitor important?

Comment: Well, not necessarily a good monitor, but one that supports the resolution you want to capture to. For example mine does 1680x1050 max and even though my hardware is powerful enough, I just can't capture in 1080p because the game can't run in that resolution. You should be certain which resolution you want to capture to. 1080p is probably the bare minimum these days. The future is with 2k and 4k. But this comes down to what you can afford as higher resolution monitors are pretty expensive.